# Using conda to install outdated requirements.yml packages for environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have created a new environment and would like to base it off of the requirements.yml file at

https://github.com/decomp-sem/neural-sprl/blob/master/requirements.yml

but when I run

conda env update --prefix ./env --file requirements.yml

I obtain a ResolvePackageNotFound error listing many of the packages in the .yml file. I tried moving the listed packages under the pip header but that doesn't help. I'm not sure if this being based on Python 2 code is a part of the issue, too.

Comment: Why not go the other way? First, use the YAML to create a new environment, then mutate to include additional packages. The YAML is over two years old and some of the packages versions are twice that, so you'll probably need `-c free` to [enable the free channel searching](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html).

Comment: This works for almost all the packages in the .yml file, but some of them return: Pip subprocess error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement. How should these be handled? Should I remove these lines from the .yml file and go one-by-one in trying to add them manually?

Comment: It's going to be case by case - edit the YAML file to try to get rid of what doesn't work. I would point out that most of those packages in the Pip section can be transitioned to sourcing from Conda instead of Pip (change their `==` to `=` and move them under `dependencies:` instead of `pip:`; e.g., `scipy`, `pandas`, `scikit-learn`). Some can simply be removed (e.g., `sklearn` is useless - it's an empty package created to help users that actually want `scikit-learn`). I would focus as much as possible on getting a single YAML file that simply works and you don't have to do manual installs.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having issues fixing things one-by-one. For example, the recommended `conda install pytorch=0.2.0 -c pytorch` does not seem to work. It might be a better idea to seek out help from the authors.